# Leading and trailing spaces for each line from textarea

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-4

- ruby 2.1.3
- rails 4.1.7

**I want to generate a unordered list from textarea**. So I have to preserve all line breaks for each item and remove leading and trailing spaces.

Well, I'm trying to remove all leading and trailing spaces from **each line of textarea** with no success.

I'm using a regex:

```
string_from_textarea.gsub(/^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$/, '')
```

I've tried strip and rstrip rails methods with no luck too (they are working with the same result as regex):

- Leading spaces for each line are removed perfectly.
- But with trailing spaces only the last space from string is removed. But I wanna for each line.

What am I missing here? What is the deal with textarea and trailing spaces for each line?

**UPDATE**

Some code example:

I'm using a callback to save formated data.

```
after_validation: format_ingredients

def format_ingredients
    self.ingredients = @ingredients.gsub(/^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$/, "")
end
```

Form view:

```
= f.text_area :ingredients, class: 'fieldW-600 striped', rows: '10'
```

Comment: Try `/^[^\S\r\n]+|[^\S\r\n]+$/m`

Comment: Could there be some non-ASCII characters at the end?  Try this and report back: `line[-5,-1].encode('utf-8').each_char { |c| puts c.ord }`.

Comment: @sin the same result, unfortunately

Comment: Strange because `\s` should cover any Unicode breaks, and `[^\S] `equals `\s`. Are you using the regex in Unicode mode? Maybe a `//u` or something (don't know Java).

Comment: @CarySwoveland no, I'm using only latin letters and numbers. Your code has returned undefined method `encode' for nil:NilClass. I've updated my question with more information. Thanks!

Comment: I meant for `line` to be a line of your text that causes a problem.

Comment: @sin, very strange because it works with leading spaces. I'm using rails with ruby. I've updated my question with a code example.

Comment: If not multiline, you could always try the absolute anchors `/\A\s+|\s+\z/`

Comment: @CarySwoveland I've realized after, sorry. I'm crazy with this problem. I have no problem with a specific line. The trailing spaces only are removed on the end of string, but I want to remove for each line. Sorry about my english.

Comment: @sin, Yes, it's multiline. But I have the same result with your regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `String#strip`

```
'   test text with    multiple spaces      '.strip
#=> "test text with    multiple spaces"
```

To apply this to each line:

```
str = "   test \ntext with    multiple  \nspaces      "
str = str.lines.map(&:strip).join("\n")
"test\ntext with    multiple\nspaces"
```

Comment: As I wrote: I've tried strip and rstrip rails methods with no luck too (they are working with the same result as regex)

Comment: Well, have you tried what I suggested? It sure works for the example above. The only thing that could go wrong is when your string somehow contains non-breaking spaces. They look like a space but behave like a normal character. It's a common source of errors.

Comment: Sorry, you were right. Your answer solves my problem too. I didn't see "lines.maplines.map(&:strip).join("\n")", I was blind.

Answer (score 1):

I think @sin probably intimated the problem in his/her first comment. Your file was probably produced on a Windows machine that puts a carriage return/life feed pair (`"\r\n"`) at the end of each line other than (presumably) the last, where it just writes `\n`.  (Check `line[-2]` on any line other than the last.) That would account for the result you are getting:

```
r = /^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$/

str = "  testing 123  \r\n testing again  \n"
str.gsub(r, '')
  #=> "testing 123  \r\ntesting again\n"
```

If this theory is correct the fix should be just a slight tweak to your regex:

```
r = /^[ \t]+|[ \t\r]+$/

str.gsub(r, '')
  #=> "testing 123\ntesting again\n"
```

You might be able to do this with your regex by changing the value of the global variable `$/`, which is the input record separator, a newline by default. That could be a problem for the end of the last line, however, if that only has a newline.

Comment: I'm using OSX with firefox, chrome and safari. But yor regex works very well. Thanks for your answer. Works with "gsub(/^[ \t]+|[ \t]+(.)$/, '').rstrip" too.  Many people solved my problem. I will choose the oldest and best answer for me.

Comment: You mean the oldest person who submitted an answer, right?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a good use for a regexp. Instead use standard String processing methods.

If you have text that contains embedded LF ("\n") line-ends and spaces at the beginning and ends of the lines, then try this:

```
foo = "
 line 1 
  line 2
line 3
"
foo # => "\n line 1 \n  line 2\nline 3\n"
```

Here's how to clean the lines of leading/trailing white-space and re-add the line-ends:

```
bar = foo.each_line.map(&:strip).join("\n")
bar # => "\nline 1\nline 2\nline 3"
```

If you're dealing with CRLF line-ends, as a Windows system would generate text:

```
foo = "\r\n line 1 \r\n  line 2\r\nline 3\r\n"
bar = foo.each_line.map(&:strip).join("\r\n")
bar # => "\r\nline 1\r\nline 2\r\nline 3"
```

If you're dealing with the potential of having white-space that contains other forms of white-space like non-breaking spaces, then switching to a regexp that uses the POSIX `[[:space:]]` character set, that contains white-space used in all character sets. I'd do something like:

```
s.sub(/^[[:space:]]+/, '').sub(/[[:space:]]+$/, '')
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation and right appointments! Why this approach is not good for regex? I think your solution is pretty the same as given by PatrickOscity but with more informations.

Answer (score -1):

I think you might be looking for `String#lstrip` and `String#rstrip` methods:

```
str = %Q^this is a line  
and so is this  
all of the lines have two spaces at the beginning  
and also at the end  ^`

`> new_string = ""
> "" 
str.each_line do |line|
     new_string += line.rstrip.lstrip + "\n"
   end
 > "this is a line\n  and so is this  \n  all of the lines have two spaces at the beginning  \n  and also at the end  " 
2.1.2 :034 > puts new_string
this is a line
and so is this
all of the lines have two spaces at the beginning
and also at the end
> new_string
`> "this is a line\nand so is this\nall of the lines have two spaces at the beginning\nand also at the end\n"`
```

Comment: I'm generating a unordered list from textarea. So I have to preserve all line breaks for each item. As I wrote: I've tried lstrip and rstrip rails methods too.

Comment: Your example code isn't valid. I'd recommend fixing it, and copying and pasting it in EXACTLY. Also, please read the help about formatting code so your answer is more readable.

Comment: fixed the code - I called the wrong string variable inside the loop, but it's fine now.